# 2D Geometry Distorts When Translating

Tags: macos, opengl

I’ve a project that I’m using to learn OpenGL on OSX, I found it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html). I’ve modified it to so that I can start using my own textures on simple, 2D geometry.

I’m running into a problem that I know is asked often, but I can’t find the solution that works for me.

I simply want to translate the geometry so it moves left, right, up, down, but when I do so it’s shape becomes distorted.

Like this:

[image]

It should look like below but just moved on the X axis:

[image]

The code I’m using is:

```
static GLfloat modelView[16];
static GLfloat projection[16];
static GLfloat objectMvp[16];
static GLfloat model[16];
static GLfloat view[16];

mtxLoadIdentity(model);
mtxLoadIdentity(view);
mtxLoadIdentity(modelView);
mtxLoadIdentity(projection);

//load the desired projection matrix into projection var
mtxLoadPerspective(projection, 90, m_viewAspect, 0.1, 100);
//m_viewAspect is updated every time the window changes shape
//and is window.width/window.height

mtxTranslateApply(model, 0.3, 0, -500);
mtxScaleApply(model, m_viewAspect, 1, 1); //[*]
mtxRotateXApply(model, 0);
mtxRotateYApply(model, 0);
mtxRotateZApply(model, 0);
mtxScaleApply(model, 1/m_viewAspect, 1, 1); //[*]

mtxMultiply(modelView, view, model);
mtxMultiply(objectMvp, projection, modelView);

//and send objectMvp to the shader for rendering…
glUniformMatrix4fv(m_UniformIdx, 1, GL_FALSE, objectMvp);
```

All the `mtx*` functions do the matrix maths indicated and place the result into the first parameter passed. I’ve got to assume they all work correctly as they are unchanged from the original Apple example project which worked fine.

The `mtxLoadPerspective()` function’s signature is:

```
void mtxLoadPerspective(float* mtx, float fov, float aspect, float nearZ, float farZ)
```

The two `[*]` lines of code are based on answers to similar problems on other sites where the instructions were to scale in the X axis according to the aspect ratio, do the rotation and then scale back.

Am I right to assume the aspect ratio is the core of the issue? And are there any example codes that someone knows of to guide me?

EDIT: The shader uses column-major maths for the position

```
gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * inPosition;
```

as indicated by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893536/using-row-major-in-opengl-shader).

EDIT: To clarify the `mtx*` functions.

`mtxLoadPerspective()` converts the FOV like this:

```
float f = 1.0f / tanf( (fov * (M_PI/180)) / 2.0f);
```

The translate function is:

```
void mtxTranslateApply(float* mtx, float xTrans, float yTrans, float zTrans)
{

    mtx[12] += mtx[0]*xTrans + mtx[4]*yTrans + mtx[ 8]*zTrans;
    mtx[13] += mtx[1]*xTrans + mtx[5]*yTrans + mtx[ 9]*zTrans;
    mtx[14] += mtx[2]*xTrans + mtx[6]*yTrans + mtx[10]*zTrans;  
}
```

The other functions are:

```
void mtxMultiply(float* ret, const float* lhs, const float* rhs)
{
    ret[ 0] = lhs[ 0]*rhs[ 0] + lhs[ 4]*rhs[ 1] + lhs[ 8]*rhs[ 2] + lhs[12]*rhs[ 3];
    ret[ 1] = lhs[ 1]*rhs[ 0] + lhs[ 5]*rhs[ 1] + lhs[ 9]*rhs[ 2] + lhs[13]*rhs[ 3];
    ret[ 2] = lhs[ 2]*rhs[ 0] + lhs[ 6]*rhs[ 1] + lhs[10]*rhs[ 2] + lhs[14]*rhs[ 3];
    ret[ 3] = lhs[ 3]*rhs[ 0] + lhs[ 7]*rhs[ 1] + lhs[11]*rhs[ 2] + lhs[15]*rhs[ 3];

    ret[ 4] = lhs[ 0]*rhs[ 4] + lhs[ 4]*rhs[ 5] + lhs[ 8]*rhs[ 6] + lhs[12]*rhs[ 7];
    ret[ 5] = lhs[ 1]*rhs[ 4] + lhs[ 5]*rhs[ 5] + lhs[ 9]*rhs[ 6] + lhs[13]*rhs[ 7];
    ret[ 6] = lhs[ 2]*rhs[ 4] + lhs[ 6]*rhs[ 5] + lhs[10]*rhs[ 6] + lhs[14]*rhs[ 7];
    ret[ 7] = lhs[ 3]*rhs[ 4] + lhs[ 7]*rhs[ 5] + lhs[11]*rhs[ 6] + lhs[15]*rhs[ 7];

    ret[ 8] = lhs[ 0]*rhs[ 8] + lhs[ 4]*rhs[ 9] + lhs[ 8]*rhs[10] + lhs[12]*rhs[11];
    ret[ 9] = lhs[ 1]*rhs[ 8] + lhs[ 5]*rhs[ 9] + lhs[ 9]*rhs[10] + lhs[13]*rhs[11];
    ret[10] = lhs[ 2]*rhs[ 8] + lhs[ 6]*rhs[ 9] + lhs[10]*rhs[10] + lhs[14]*rhs[11];
    ret[11] = lhs[ 3]*rhs[ 8] + lhs[ 7]*rhs[ 9] + lhs[11]*rhs[10] + lhs[15]*rhs[11];

    ret[12] = lhs[ 0]*rhs[12] + lhs[ 4]*rhs[13] + lhs[ 8]*rhs[14] + lhs[12]*rhs[15];
    ret[13] = lhs[ 1]*rhs[12] + lhs[ 5]*rhs[13] + lhs[ 9]*rhs[14] + lhs[13]*rhs[15];
    ret[14] = lhs[ 2]*rhs[12] + lhs[ 6]*rhs[13] + lhs[10]*rhs[14] + lhs[14]*rhs[15];
    ret[15] = lhs[ 3]*rhs[12] + lhs[ 7]*rhs[13] + lhs[11]*rhs[14] + lhs[15]*rhs[15];
}

void mtxScaleApply(float* mtx, float xScale, float yScale, float zScale)
{
    mtx[ 0] *= xScale;
    mtx[ 4] *= yScale;
    mtx[ 8] *= zScale;

    mtx[ 1] *= xScale;
    mtx[ 5] *= yScale;
    mtx[ 9] *= zScale;

    mtx[ 2] *= xScale;
    mtx[ 6] *= yScale;
    mtx[10] *= zScale;

    mtx[ 3] *= xScale;
    mtx[ 7] *= yScale;
    mtx[11] *= xScale;
}

void mtxRotateXMatrix(float* mtx, float rad)
{
    float cosrad = cosf(rad);
    float sinrad = sinf(rad);

    float mtx01 = mtx[ 1];
    float mtx05 = mtx[ 5];
    float mtx09 = mtx[ 9];
    float mtx13 = mtx[13];

    mtx[ 1] = cosrad*mtx01 - sinrad*mtx[ 2];
    mtx[ 2] = sinrad*mtx01 + cosrad*mtx[ 2];

    mtx[ 5] = cosrad*mtx05 - sinrad*mtx[ 6];
    mtx[ 6] = sinrad*mtx05 + cosrad*mtx[ 6];

    mtx[ 9] = cosrad*mtx09 - sinrad*mtx[10];
    mtx[10] = sinrad*mtx09 + cosrad*mtx[10];

    mtx[13] = cosrad*mtx13 - sinrad*mtx[14];
    mtx[14] = sinrad*mtx13 + cosrad*mtx[14];
}


void mtxRotateYMatrix(float* mtx, float rad)
{
    float cosrad = cosf(rad);
    float sinrad = sinf(rad);

    float mtx00 = mtx[ 0];
    float mtx04 = mtx[ 4];
    float mtx08 = mtx[ 8];
    float mtx12 = mtx[12];

    mtx[ 0] = cosrad*mtx00 - sinrad*mtx[ 2];
    mtx[ 2] = sinrad*mtx00 + cosrad*mtx[ 2];

    mtx[ 4] = cosrad*mtx04 - sinrad*mtx[ 6];
    mtx[ 6] = sinrad*mtx04 + cosrad*mtx[ 6];

    mtx[ 8] = cosrad*mtx08 - sinrad*mtx[10];
    mtx[10] = sinrad*mtx08 + cosrad*mtx[10];

    mtx[12] = cosrad*mtx12 - sinrad*mtx[14];
    mtx[14] = sinrad*mtx12 + cosrad*mtx[14];
}


void mtxRotateZMatrix(float* mtx, float rad)
{
    float cosrad = cosf(rad);
    float sinrad = sinf(rad);

    float mtx00 = mtx[ 0];
    float mtx04 = mtx[ 4];
    float mtx08 = mtx[ 8];
    float mtx12 = mtx[12];

    mtx[ 0] = cosrad*mtx00 - sinrad*mtx[ 1];
    mtx[ 1] = sinrad*mtx00 + cosrad*mtx[ 1];

    mtx[ 4] = cosrad*mtx04 - sinrad*mtx[ 5];
    mtx[ 5] = sinrad*mtx04 + cosrad*mtx[ 5];

    mtx[ 8] = cosrad*mtx08 - sinrad*mtx[ 9];
    mtx[ 9] = sinrad*mtx08 + cosrad*mtx[ 9];

    mtx[12] = cosrad*mtx12 - sinrad*mtx[13];
    mtx[13] = sinrad*mtx12 + cosrad*mtx[13];
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how those `mtx*()` functions are implemented. For example, `mtxLoadPerspective()` does take the angle in degrees, not radians? I'm actually surprised that you see anything at all, since you have a translation by -500 in z-direction, but your far plane is only 100 away. My main suspects are a problem with multiplication order, or transposition. But this all depends on whether the `mtx*()` function operate with row- or column major matrices, and in what order `mtxMultiply()` multiplies.

Comment: The far plane should be 1000, that's something I must've tweaked by mistake, but yes, it is strange I still see something. The mtx* functions are listed as column-major.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I finally got the code to work, but I'm not clear why.

In a general, overall manner, I loaded identity matrices into the `view`, `model`, and `projection`.

The x, y, z scaling is applied to the `model` matrix.

The x, y, z rotation is then applied to the `model` matrix.

The x and y translation is applied to the `model` as well.

The z translation, however, is applied to the `view` matrix (although I do understand the concept of moving the camera back to see the geometry, I just don't see why applying the x and y translations to the `view` matrix does nothing).

I then do the multiplication `model * view`, this goes into the `modelView` matrix.

Then do `modelView * projection` and this product is sent to the shader.

If anyone could comment and shed light on this I'd be grateful, but in the meantime I'll blunder on.